# why is "I have been to a place last year" not correct

Tags: tense

The sentence is "I have been to a place last year".
Why is this sentence not correct and how can I correct it.

Comment: Hello Salluc.  Why do you think it is not correct?  What grammar do you see in this sentence?  What have you studied about this grammar?  I do like to know what you have already found out before answering.  It means that I don't repeat what you already know.

Comment: As it stands, there is a very similar question.  Take a look and if it does answer your question you can close this one as a "duplicate"